# Use 2 Mouse Cursors on the same Computer

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor

I understand that questions like this have being answered before, however mine is slightly different.

Basically I run automated tests which mean that the mouse cursor is moving around the screen clicking things for a bit of time. I am completely out of action while this is going on.

I have already tried to use VirtualBox to set up a linux OS that I can use while the tests are running, but the Computer still only likes to use one cursor and either the tests fail or I cant use virtualbox.

**Is there anyway I can use two cursors on the same Screen at the same time?** I have dual monitors and a dual core cpu if that helps.

Comment: Why don't you run the tests in a VM? Which would have its own cursor.

Comment: my VM is linux which won't run Visual Studio 2012 and I wont be able to install windows on the VM.

Comment: I saw this one http://teamplayer.uptodown.com/

Comment: are the automated tests in a browser? if so, is running it headlessly an option?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do what you are asking, despite your saying in comments that you can't install Windows in a VM, probably *is* **another Windows installation in a VM.** I had a quick look and even a non-OEM Windows 7 Ultimate can be had for around $300. Alternatively, if you have MSDN it should be included in the price you are already paying.

When you have installed Windows and whatever is required to run the tests (note that you don't necessarily need a full-blown Visual Studio installation), you can simply start the VM, start the test process, and then detach from the VM and let it do its thing while you keep working.

As for having two mouse cursors in the same session, **I'm not even sure Windows supports that** and it certainly would risk wreaking havoc with basic Win32 API functions like [GetCursorPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The related Win32 API functions all seem to talk about "the cursor" and deal with a single position, which while not proof seems to me to be a strong indication that Windows doesn't do multiple mouse cursors.

Comment: your probably right, it's just for convenience i'm not going to bother with all that, I was hoping someone would know of some program that would do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked into it very much but [Mouse Mischief](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-mischief/en-us/default.aspx) appears to let you do this, but I'm not yet clear if it's only during a Powerpoint presentation or if it works without Powerpoint being launched.

You'd need two mice, of course.

Comment: "Mouse Mischief integrates into Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 and Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007"

How is that any help and I dont have or want to use two mice.

Comment: Yeah I'm playing with it a bit ... won't work like I thought it did.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple [usb KVM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182157) with both ports plugged into the same machine, just forward one of the USB interfaces to the VM.

Does cost time and money to obtain it (though not as much as purchasing another license for windows) and is not a software solution, but it doesn't require you to use more than one mouse.

Comment: can you use a virtual KVM? =D

Comment: @matthiasgh None that I know unfortunately. I did a little bit of searching and nothing seemed to come up.

Answer (score 0):

You can (sort of) achieve two cursors by using [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.org).  This program is free while in beta and supports creation of up to four different cursors attached to hardware mice.  However, as this is an issue with such a low-level concept in operating systems, most system elements don't respond to the virtual cursors.  Therefore, the usefulness of this program depends on what you're trying to do alongside the tests you are running with the main cursor.